# How to pass encrypted message and passphrase when using `os.system` to call gpg?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, encryption, gnupg

I have an encrypted message as a string in python. I want to decrypt it with a program called gpg.

In terminal, using gpg requires:

1. gpg --decrypt -a
2. Then it prompts you for the encrypted message
3. Then it prompts for private key.

[image]

Is there a way to do all of this in python when the encrypted message is saved in a variable in python? I know you use the os module to make terminal commands to other programs.

```
import os
import getpass
message = '093j0rawrkj2or2r'
private_key = getpass.getpass()
os.system("gpg --decrypt -a")
...?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To input the encrypted string, you can `echo` it out first then pipe in the `gpg` command.

```
echo <message> | gpg --decrypt ...
```

To input the passphrase, there are a number of ways [depending on your env and gpg version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase). What worked on my **Ubuntu 18.04.2** with **gpg 2.2.4** was to use `--pinentry-mode=loopback` and then passing in `--passphrase`:

```
gpg --decrypt -a --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase="yourpassphrase"
```

The Python code will then look something like this:

```
import os

message = '093j0rawrkj2or2r'
command = "echo '{}' | gpg --decrypt -a --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase=yourpassphrase".format(message)
os.system(command)
```

But putting the actual `--passphrase-yourpassphrase` is very insecure. An alternative is to put the passphrase in some file then use `--passphrase-file` option instead.

```
import os

message = '093j0rawrkj2or2r'
command = "echo '{}' | gpg --decrypt -a --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-file=yourpassphrasefile".format(message)
os.system(command)
```

I don't know where you got the encrypted message, but I usually work with encrypted *files*. If the encrypted input is from a file, just replace `echo <string>` with `cat <filepath>`:

```
cat somefile.txt | gpg --decrypt -a --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-file=yourpassphrasefile
```

Comment: are there any risks to putting the private key password in this way? Or in doing things in this way?

Comment: @Qwertford Well, I think as long as you **don't** commit the passphrase (hardcoded string or passphrase file) and private keys into any repository, or share/distribute them publicly, it should be OK. They should only be available locally on your machine. If you *really* need to share them with other people or with other machines, I suggest reading about how to securely export/import GPG keys.

Comment: Another option, instead of using `--passphrase-file=<file>` (which requires a file on disk), is to use `--passphrase-fd=0` to provide the password from standard input.